# Too many values to unpack. Error during python programming

Tags: python

I am trying to make a huffman tree program such that it converts a given hash into a huffman tree. I want to return a list of tuples with each tuple having the child element, its frequency, parent element and an assigned value 0 0r 1.

But when I run the code, it shows too many values to unpack. Can you verify my code?

```
temp_var = -1

new_heap = []
stack_heap = []
ref_hash = freq_table.copy()
len_freqtable = len(freq_table)
while(len_freqtable > 1):

    new_heap.append(pop(freq_table))
    new_heap.append(pop(freq_table))
    pop_first = new_heap.pop(0)
    freq_first = ref_hash[pop_first]
    pop_second = new_heap.pop(0)
    freq_second = ref_hash[pop_second]
    append_composite = pop_first + pop_second
    stack_heap.append((pop_first,freq_first,append_composite,'0'))

    stack_heap.append((pop_second,freq_second,append_composite,'1'))
    freq_table[append_composite] = freq_first + freq_second
    ref_hash[append_composite] = freq_first + freq_second
    len_freqtable = len_freqtable - 1
    temp_var = temp_var - 1 

return stack_heap
```

Comment: Post the exact error traceback.

Comment: Can't this error only occur in a situation like `a, b, ... = stuff`? Don't see any of those in the code.

Comment: @tobias_k: That's why we want to see the traceback.

Answer (score 4):

You most certainly do something like this

```
def myFunction()
    return (1,1,1)

a,b = myFunction()   #raises an 'Too many values to unpack' Error

a,b,c = myFunction() #this works

a = myFunction() # this works too, a is now a tuple
```

Check all return values of your functions and see if the number of elements you return are as expected.